# how to save filename of file upload in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form that implement field upload more than 1 file. but i still confused how to store it to mysql. i just wanna to make all the file saved in mysql with just once submit. i need your help.

this is my controller :

```
function do_upload() {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpeg|png|gif|jpg|txt|docs';
        $config['max_size'] = '2000';
        $config['max_width']  = '2000';
        $config['max_height']  = '2000';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value) {

            if (!empty($value['tmp_name'])) {

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($key)) {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                } else {
                }
            }
        }
}
```

and this is my view :

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>
<input type="file" name="file1" />
<input type="file" name="file2"/>
<input type="file" name="file3"/>
</div>
<br /><br/>
<input type="submit" value="upload" name="upload" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

When upload succeeds, `$this->upload->do_upload($key)` returns some data.

Have a look here: [CI3 Docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#CI_Upload::do_upload)

So, save it into a variable, say `$data` like,

```
$data = $this->upload->do_upload($key);
```

which will be an array, and access uploaded file's name with `$data['file_name']`. Which will be in the else condition of your code.